# Time machine migration has been preparing for 14 hours, is this normal?

Tags: time-machine, migration-assistant

There's very little information on how long time machine migrations are supposed to take on Google. I have 200GB or so under my user and it has been stuck on "preparing to transfer user documents" for 14 hours.

[image]

What's a normal time? Can I see the progress somehow without interrupting it? Should I just cancel it?

Comment: Not normal. What's the connection method to the Time Machine backup?

Comment: 802.11ac local network.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just cancel out of it and attempt again.

Comment: I'd also wire up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's because our time capsule is incredibly slow just generall, it takes 20 seconds - 1 minute to open a folder, "preparing" to copy a reasonable folder can take 10's of minutes. This is independently of me being plugged in directly to the time capsule or going over wireless.

There doesn't seem to be a solution except possibly to do a factory reset, but first I'm going to get a 2TB disk and use the airport disk archiving function to save what I have.

I've found a few threads where people similar issues, like this one:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471457?tstart=0